# How to put solrconfig.xml and schema.xml using solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I'd like to put new `solrconfig.xml` and `schema.xml` using solrj.
I already found [SchemaRquest](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_7_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/schema/SchemaRequest.html). But, It provides only some functions Add/Update/Delete.
What I want to do is that define `solrconfig.xml` and `schema.xml` first and put it into a collection and use it using solrj.

Comment: you can use zookeeper to download and upload solrconfig.xml and shema.xml (all config files).

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a SolrCloud setup you can do this:

```
$SOLR_HOME/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost zkhost:3181 -confname example-cmd putfile /configs/example/managed-schema ./managed-schema
```

If you want to do with Java, you can do something like this:

```
ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper(host, tick * 15, this);
zk.setData(PATH_IN_ZK, contentString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), -1);
```